# Dropdownlist inside a gridview not working when selection changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, pagertemplate

I have two dropdownlist inside a gridview.

1. 1st Dropdown -- For Selecting the `Page No`.
2. 2nd Dropdown -- For Selecting the `Page Size`.

**The Issue related to the dropdownlist is:-**

When I `change` the Selection it works fine and shows me the exact result. But When I bring the selection to the last value again my `gridview` breaks. Tried with all the code and debugged also but couldn't find the exact solution.

Please see the aspx code for the `dropdownlist` inside the `Gridview`:-

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="grdUser"
                    OnPageIndexChanging="grdUser_PageIndexChanging"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="false" EnableViewState="true"
                    AllowPaging="true"
                    OnDataBound="grdUser_DataBound"
                    runat="server"
                    Width="100%"
                    border="1"
                    DataKeyNames="Id"
                    PageSize="2">

                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDelete" runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="UserName" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email Id" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="usertype" HeaderText="UserType" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="active" HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" HeaderStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" AlternateText="Delete" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" ItemStyle-Width="15" EditImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" ShowEditButton="True" ControlStyle-Width="15" ControlStyle-Height="15" CancelImageUrl="~/images/close.png" UpdateImageUrl="~/images/update.png">
                            <ControlStyle Height="20px" Width="20px"></ControlStyle>
                        </asp:CommandField>
                    </Columns>

                    <PagerStyle ForeColor="Blue"
                        BackColor="LightBlue" />
                    <PagerTemplate>
                        <table style="width: 100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="col-md-7">
                                    <asp:Label ID="MessageLabel"
                                        ForeColor="Blue"
                                        Text="Select a page:"
                                        runat="server" />
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="FirstLB" runat="server" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="First" ToolTip="First"><<</asp:LinkButton>

                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="PrevLB" runat="server" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Prev" ToolTip="Previous"><</asp:LinkButton>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="PageDropDownList"
                                        AutoPostBack="true"
                                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="PageDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                        runat="server" />
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="NextLB" runat="server" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Next" ToolTip="Next">></asp:LinkButton>

                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LastLB" runat="server" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Last" ToolTip="Last">>></asp:LinkButton>
                                </td>
                                <td class="col-md-3">
                                    <asp:Label ID="PageSizeLabel" runat="server" Text="Select Page Size: "></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPageSize" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPageSize_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="2" />
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="5" />
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="10" Text="10" />
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </td>
                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                    <asp:Label ID="CurrentPageLabel"
                                        ForeColor="Blue"
                                        runat="server" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </PagerTemplate>
                </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Note: The Gridview is under the `UpdatePanel`.

Also see the Code behind for the each event and the `BindGrid();`

```
protected void BindGrid()
    {
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Id,username,email,usertype,active from tbl_User ORDER By Id DESC");
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    grdUser.DataSource = dt;
                    grdUser.DataBind();
                    DisablePageDirections();
                    // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    //return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void DisablePageDirections()
    {
        if (grdUser.PageIndex == 0)
        {
            (grdUser.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("FirstLB") as LinkButton).Enabled = false;
            (grdUser.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("PrevLB") as LinkButton).Enabled = false;
        }
        if (grdUser.PageIndex == grdUser.PageCount - 1)
        {
            (grdUser.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("NextLB") as LinkButton).Enabled = false;
            (grdUser.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("LastLB") as LinkButton).Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    protected void ddlPageSize_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow pagerRow = grdUser.BottomPagerRow;
        DropDownList pageSizeList = (DropDownList)pagerRow.Cells[0].FindControl("ddlPageSize");
        grdUser.PageSize = Convert.ToInt32(pageSizeList.SelectedValue);
        Context.Session["PageSize"] = pageSizeList.SelectedValue;
        BindGrid();
    }
    protected void PageDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow pagerRow = grdUser.BottomPagerRow;
        DropDownList pageList = (DropDownList)pagerRow.Cells[0].FindControl("PageDropDownList");
        grdUser.PageIndex = pageList.SelectedIndex;
        BindGrid();
    }
```

Also see the gridview databound Event:-

```
protected void grdUser_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow pagerRow = grdUser.BottomPagerRow;
        DropDownList pageSizeList = (DropDownList)pagerRow.Cells[0].FindControl("ddlPageSize");
        if (Context.Session["PageSize"] != null)
        {
            pageSizeList.SelectedValue = Context.Session["PageSize"].ToString();
        }
        // Retrieve the DropDownList and Label controls from the row.
        DropDownList pageList = (DropDownList)pagerRow.Cells[0].FindControl("PageDropDownList");
        Label pageLabel = (Label)pagerRow.Cells[0].FindControl("CurrentPageLabel");
        if (pageList != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < grdUser.PageCount; i++)
            {
                int pageNumber = i + 1;
                ListItem item = new ListItem(pageNumber.ToString());
                if (i == grdUser.PageIndex)
                {
                    item.Selected = true;
                }
                pageList.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
        if (pageLabel != null)
        {
            int currentPage = grdUser.PageIndex + 1;
            pageLabel.Text = "Page " + currentPage.ToString() + " of " + grdUser.PageCount.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Also, there is no problem in the `ddlPageSize` and it is working fine

Comment: what error you get ??

Comment: @AnantDabhi: I m not getting the error, when I bounce back the selection to the default, the grids get break..

Comment: What does "gridview breaks" mean? It shows no info, or it is not updated, or markup is broken, or what?

Comment: @Andrei: `break` here means, See the link. http://www.imagesup.net/?di=13141926054616. It gets like this when I move the selection to the normal/default

Comment: @Andrei: This ddl `<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPageSize" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPageSize_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="2" />
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="5" />
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="10" Text="10" />
                                        </asp:DropDownList>`.Also see the `listitem` for specific value

Comment: @NadeemKhan, where does the data fro `PageDropDownList` come from? I suppose you bind it somehow? Esppecially I am curious as to how the default value is set

Comment: @Andrei: The data comes from the table, you can see the code for more details. I am setting the default value from `listitem`.

Comment: @NadeemKhan, sorry, I must be missing something. For page size dropdown i see how you are setting the data and the default value. But for page number?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67477/discussion-between-nadeem-khan-and-andrei).

Comment: @Andrei: Sorry was in meeting, Can we discuss on this now ?

Comment: @Andrei: Please see the updated code and full information. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the below part

```
protected void grdUser_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //...
            for (int i = 0; i < grdUser.PageCount; i++)
            {
                int pageNumber = i + 1;
                ListItem item = new ListItem(pageNumber.ToString());
                if (i == grdUser.PageIndex)
                {
                    item.Selected = true;
                }
                pageList.Items.Add(item);
            }
        //...
    }
```

As you try to populate `PageDropDownList` to reflect current grid `PageCount` and select the current page

You may think of a better way to pupolate that dropdown without breaking the grid

But my recommendation is to use a `TextBox` for `CurrentPage` rather than `DropDownList`

**Why?**

Assume the grid has 1000s of pages, and user wants page number 5555. your approach enforces the user to scroll in the `DropDownList` from 1 to 5555, it would be more or less as if the user kept navigation through pages till reach his/her target page.

While `TextBox` will allow the end user to select the page by just typing its number

And it will save you from the hassle of populating that `DropDownList` and hopefully fix your issue

### UPDATE:

Using `TextBox`, your code should look something like this *(but I did not write a full solution to test it)*

**In Aspx, replace the `PageDropDownList` control with the text box as follows**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPageNumber" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtPageNumber_TextChanged" runat="server" />
```

**In code behinde, replace `PageDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged` event handler with the following one**

```
protected void txtPageNumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow pagerRow = grdUser.BottomPagerRow;
        TextBox txtPageNumber = (TextBox)sender;
        //Note you need to do more validation on the entered value 
        //Do not allow strings, floats, etc
        int currentPage = int.Parse(txtPageNumber.Text);
        //To handle entries larger than page count        
        if(currentPage >= grdUser.PageCount)
        {
         grdUser.PageIndex = grdUser.PageCount - 1;
         txtPageNumber.Text = grdUser.PageIndex.ToString();             
        }
        else 
          grdUser.PageIndex  = currentPage;

        BindGrid();
    }
```

**And finally update `grdUser_DataBound` as follows**

```
protected void grdUser_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //...... your original code here
        //DropDownList pageList = (DropDownList)pagerRow.Cells[0].FindControl("PageDropDownList");
        TextBox txtPageNumber = (TextBox)pagerRow.Cells[0].FindControl("txtPageNumber");
        txtPageNumber.Text = grdUser.PageIndex.ToString();
        //Label pageLabel = (Label)pagerRow.Cells[0].FindControl("CurrentPageLabel");
        // if (pageList != null)
        // {
            // for (int i = 0; i < grdUser.PageCount; i++)
            // {
                // int pageNumber = i + 1;
                // ListItem item = new ListItem(pageNumber.ToString());
                // if (i == grdUser.PageIndex)
                // {
                    // item.Selected = true;
                // }
                // pageList.Items.Add(item);
            // }
        // }
        //...... your original code here
    }
```

Comment: mGouda: As per your suggestion, for using textbox. Can you give me a brief sample with code, So I can implement and check. ?

Comment: I have added sample code to my answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In my earlier answer, I tried to handle the technical challenge with Microsoft `GridView`.

But for commercial applications, I suggest using a third part `GridView` from vendors like Telerik, DevExpress, Infragistics, ComponentOne, etc.

Because most `GridViews` provided by those vendors provide built in functionality for simple things like paging, customizing page size, and more

Based on this answer, you will not write any line of code to worry about customizing page size at run time or similar stuff

[Check this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/functionality/paging/custom-paging/defaultcs.aspx)

Comment: i think, this one will be the good to implement..Can you help me in implementing this ?

Comment: This is not just a matter of how to implement, you need to purchase a package as it is a payed thing, you can just google the names I mentioned and google will lead you to their websites that are full of demos and explanation. for example the link I provided in the answer explains with details how to create the demo. Then once you decide which vendor to go to, you purchase their package and be eligible for their technical support

Comment: thanks Gouda: But for accepting your answer means my gridview is working, which is still not. There are other several things which are on free and also we gets support. That's why we all are here. Purchasing will never be a option. Anyways thanks. But I will mark answer when I succesfully implement this on my own..